rsnapshot - Not working as expected. Each snapshot similar size
I am using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and trying to backup the system using rsnapshot.
I have installed rsnapshot and configured it to backup selected directories to the remote disk(btrfs, nfs4) mounted to /mnt/sys-backup/. md1 on the Ubuntu system is xfs, raid 1.
The issue is that it seems like each backup snapshot has similar size although I expected minimal increase between the snapshots. Below is the result from my terminal:
root@dalegal-server-w:/mnt/sys-backup/dalegal-server-w/snapshots
# du -sh --count-links */
7.0G basic_setting_after_install/
42G daily.0/
41G hourly.0/
37G hourly.1/
37G hourly.10/
43G hourly.11/
37G hourly.2/
37G hourly.3/
37G hourly.4/
37G hourly.5/
37G hourly.6/
37G hourly.7/
37G hourly.8/
37G hourly.9/

root@dalegal-server-w:/mnt/sys-backup/dalegal-server-w/snapshots
# du -sh */
7.0G basic_setting_after_install/
42G daily.0/
34G hourly.0/
29G hourly.1/
29G hourly.10/
29G hourly.11/
29G hourly.2/
29G hourly.3/
29G hourly.4/
29G hourly.5/
29G hourly.6/
29G hourly.7/
29G hourly.8/
29G hourly.9/


I suspect rsnapshot isn't functioning properly. Isn't rsnapshot supposed to compare the system and backup only differences using hard links?
Please help me.
